# Django Rest Framework Serializers: read_only parameter has no effect

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, permissions, serialization

Read Only settings doesn't work properly.

No matter if I use `read_only_fields`:

```
read_only_fields = ('id', 'user', 'created_at', 'account_type', 'balance', 'iban')
```

or `read_only` for each serializer field:

```
class BankAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    id = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True) 
    user = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField(read_only=True)
    account_name = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=False)
    account_type = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    balance = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)
    iban = serializers.StringRelatedField(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = BankAccount
        fields = '__all__'

    def get_created_at(self, instance):
        return instance.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y")
```

This is what my database model looks like:

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
                             on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                             related_name='bankaccounts')
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    account_type = models.CharField(max_length=10,
                                    choices=POSITIONS)
    balance = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=12)
    iban = models.CharField(max_length=22)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.iban)
```

My permission classes are the following ones:

```
permission_classes = [IsUserOrReadOnly, IsAuthenticated]
```

Whereby the custom `IsUserOrReadOnly` class looks like this:

```
class IsUserOrReadOnly(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        if request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHODS:
            return True
        return obj.user == request.user
```

My serializer/view looks like this:

```
class BankAccountViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = BankAccount.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "iban"
    serializer_class = BankAccountSerializer
    permission_class = [IsUserOrReadOnly, IsAuthenticated]
```

What I get from the api endpoint (options method response) is not the result I am expecting, means the field `account_name` is still `"read_only": true,` as can be seen in the browsable api output:

```
"actions": {
    "PUT": {
        "id": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "Id"
        },
        "user": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "User"
        },
        "created_at": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "Created at"
        },
        "account_name": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "Account name"
        },
        "account_type": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "Account type"
        },
        "balance": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "Balance"
        },
        "iban": {
            "type": "field",
            "required": false,
            "read_only": true,
            "label": "Iban"
        }
    }
}
```

What could here be wrong?

Comment: Can you please show the exact serializer/view. It looks like you might put the settings at the wrong place.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I have updated the question with view code

Comment: can you add your ***complte `BankAccountSerializer` class*** ?

Comment: @JPG I have updated the question with it

Comment: can you also add the `BankAccount` model?

Comment: @JPG I have updated the question with it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have to specify all the model fields in your serializer since you are using the **`ModelSerializer`**
Try the below serializer,

```
class BankAccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    created_at = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = BankAccount
        fields = '__all__'
        read_only_fields = ('id', 'user', 'created_at', 'account_type', 'balance', 'iban')

    def get_created_at(self, instance):
        return instance.created_at.strftime("%B %d %Y")
```

Answer (score 2):

[StringRelatedField is **read_only**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield).

You can try using [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield) instead or [nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#nested-relationships).

Comment: Thanks! But in SlugRelatedField the `slug_field` argument is required, this sounds somehow wrong for this purpose. I also don't need nested fields...

Comment: You can can have __2 serializers__ - one for __read with StringRelatedField__ and one for __write with writeable field__ - i.e. string ArrrayField; and in serializer for write __implement [create()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#saving-instances)__ method to create and save related instances. Then, in your __view override `[get_serializer_class()](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/#get_serializer_classself)`__ to choose which serializer to use based on request method.

Comment: For generic views - `OPTIONS` request with base [SimpleMetadata](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/metadata/#setting-the-metadata-scheme)  - imho should use `POST` serializer to get available api options